# How to query OrientDB with conditions on embedded string set?

Tags: orientdb

Here's an example entry in my `items` schema:

```
{
  "name": "Item1",
  "badges": ["heavy", "wooden"]
}
```

I'd like to query for all items where badges **don't** contain ("heavy" and "wooden"). 
Is it possible with OrientDB? Can index be used for such query?
For comparison, I can easily get such documents in MongoDB:

```
db.items.find({'$and': [{'badges': {$ne: 'heavy'}}, {'badges': {$ne: 'wooden'}}]})
```

(it uses index if set on the `badges` field)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of query:

```
select from items where not ('heavy' in badges) and not ('wooden' in badges)
```

Hope it helps.